# Generate CSV files with headers

Tags: apache-flink

I am generating CSV outputs from tuples. I can't find a way of generating headers in the files. Could anyone confirm whether this is possible or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flink: Write tuples with CSV header into file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54530755/flink-write-tuples-with-csv-header-into-file)

Answer (score 1):

it might be possible, but I haven't found it. I added a flatmap function upstream that (a) converted the output POJO to a string, and (b) did a one-shot injection of the header row. But there are concerns with state recovery, to ensure it always and only gets written out once.