# Apache Flink: How can I add header to a CSV file using the writeAsFormattedText sink?

Tags: apache-flink

I am using Apache Flink framework dataset API to extract data from various sources, transform it and load it to various sinks.
During this period, I am working to some scenarios where datasets of POJOs are loaded to CSV files. For this purpose, I am using writeAsFormattedText method if Flink framework and the respective text formatters in order to avoid mapping our data to tuples (and use writeTextAsCsv). One of my requirements is to add a header row on top of the CSV file produced. For example,

id,name,age
1,john,30
2,helen,42

How can such requirement be covered using the dataset API of the Apache Flink?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [Generate CSV files with headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54463386/generate-csv-files-with-headers/54467257#54467257).