# Flink: Write tuples with CSV header into file

Tags: csv, dataset, apache-flink

I did some data processing using Flink (1.7.1 with Hadoop). At the end I'd like to write the dataset consisting of 2-tuples into a file. Currently, I am doing it like this:

```
<Tuple2<Integer, Point>> pointsClustered = points.getClusteredPoints(...);
pointsClustered.writeAsCsv(params.get("output"), "\n", ",");
```

However, I would like to have the CSV headers written into the first line. The [Flink's Javadoc API](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/java/DataSet.html) doesn't state any options for this. Furthermore, I couldn't find any solution googling for it.

Could you kindly advise on how to accomplish that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flink's own `CsvOutputFormat` does not support this functionality. What you could do is to extend the `CsvOutputFormat` and override the `open` method which writes the header when the format is opened. Then you would use `DataSet#output` to specify the newly created output format:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    DataSource<Integer> input = env.fromElements(1, 2, 3);
    DataSet<Tuple3<Integer, String, Double>> result = input.map((MapFunction<Integer, Tuple3<Integer, String, Double>>) integer -> Tuple3.of(integer, integer.toString(), 42.0));

    Path outputPath = new Path("hdfs:///foobar");
    result.output(new MyCsvOutputFormat(outputPath));

    env.execute();
}

private static class MyCsvOutputFormat<T extends Tuple> extends CsvOutputFormat<T> {

    public MyCsvOutputFormat(Path outputPath) {
        super(outputPath);
    }

    @Override
    public void open(int taskNumber, int numTasks) throws IOException {
        try (PrintWriter wrt = new PrintWriter(stream)) {
            wrt.println("Foo|bar|foobar");
        }
        super.open(taskNumber, numTasks);
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed, do you wanna contribute this to Flink @JulienNioche?

Comment: Does not work. `stream` is null, because it is initialized in `super.open`. 

And if you do it the other way (calling `super.open` before using the stream), then you get a `ClosedChannelException`.

An another option could have been to use the `wrt` writer, but it has private access...

Comment: What seems to work : call `super.open` first, remove the *try-with-resources* (so that the stream doesn't get closed), and add a call to `wrt.flush()`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around the limitation by simply adding a header row to the dataset using a union. This way the first row will always be the header row of the export.

```
DataSet<Tuple8<String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String>> headers = env.fromElements(
            Tuple8.of(
                 "SDMId", "ActivityType", "ActionType", "ActivityId", "ActivityLevel", "Timestamp", "SessionId", "Value"
            ));

DataSet<Tuple8<String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String>> results =
            headers.union(skillResults);

results.writeAsCsv("file:///Users/karthsub/Desktop/first_export.csv", FileSystem.WriteMode.OVERWRITE).setParallelism(1);
```

Comment: Sometimes it is not working - header can be written as last but not first line. Probably it depends on data size and parallelism, in some cases header even is written in the middle of file.